# Why my listview is empty?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a arraylist in which users can input their text. And it is displayed in the screen as a listview. That works, but when i try to get the values of the arraylist it says that: Invalid index 0, size is 0. So im guessing for some reason the listview isnt populating?

This is how I add values to the list:

```
public class ZaidejaiActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    public Button mBtnIstrinti;
    public Button mBtnPrideti;
    public Button mBtnPradeti;
    public EditText mYrasytiVarda;
    public ListView mZaidejai;

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zaidejai);
        mBtnPrideti = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pridėtiBtn);
        mBtnPrideti.setOnClickListener(this);
        mYrasytiVarda = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.VardoYrasymoBtn);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);

        // set the mZaidejai variable to your list in the xml

        mZaidejai = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sarašas);
        mZaidejai.setAdapter(adapter);
        mZaidejai.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            // remove item from List.


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                list.remove(position);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ZaidejaiActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Delete?");
                builder.setTitle("Confirm Action");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    //checked.clear();
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                builder.create();
                builder.show();
            }
        });
        mBtnPradeti = (Button) findViewById(R.id.žaistiBtn);
        mBtnPradeti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // count items
                int i;
                for (i = adapter.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    String obj = adapter.getItem(i);
                    // send items to other activity

                    Intent pradetiZaidima = new Intent(v.getContext(), ZaidimasActivity.class);
                    pradetiZaidima.putExtra("playerList", obj);
                    startActivity(pradetiZaidima);

                }
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String input = mYrasytiVarda.getText().toString();
        if(input.length() > 0)
        {
            // add string to the adapter, not the listview
            adapter.add(input);



            // no need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); as it is done by the adapter.add() method
        }else{
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Klaida:");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Blogai yrašytas vardas");
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
// here you can add functions
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
        }

    }
```

**EDIT**

In this activity I want to get the values of the list:

```
public class ZaidimasActivity extends ZaidejaiActivity {

    public TextView mZaidejas;
    public TextView mKlausimas;
    public Button mKitasKlausimas;
    public Button mGryzti;
         @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_zaidimas);
             /** //get the player list from ZaidejaiActivity
            Bundle recdData = getIntent().getExtras();
            String myVal = recdData.getString("playerList"); */


            //show the first players name

            mZaidejas = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ZaidejoVardas);
            mZaidejas.setText(list.get(0));


           /** mGryzti = (Button)findViewById(R.id.GryztiMeniuBtn);

            mKitasKlausimas = (Button)findViewById(R.id.KitasBtn);
            mKitasKlausimas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                }
            });
     */
```

Comment: `list==empty` add values on it like `list.add("ABC");`

Comment: At what point do you populate your list? Looking at your code, you don't add anything to your list.

Comment: A user populates the list himself. When he opens the app, in the edittext(the last OnClick method) he ads some text.(f.e. name) and presses the button. And that name is added to the list. Thats how I want the list to populate.

Comment: If your using the adapter to add the items, why the list your passing, also use notifydatasetchange over the adapter after any changes to the data set.

Comment: when you obtain this error? when click on list item? or button that leads to new activity?

Comment: I add two names to the list(for example: Tom and Ben). They are displayed on the screen in a listview and i can delete them. But when i press the button next that should take me to the activity with the displayed first name i get the error.

Comment: ok. you are using for loop. do you really need to start many activities?
or do you need to start only one activity with selected name?

Comment: Yes i know that. What i want to do is when the activity starts with the first name there is a button next and then the second name appears.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your `list==empty`. So add some values on it.

```
list.add("ABC");
list.add("XYZ");
```

and then `setAdapter`

```
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);

 mZaidejai = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sarašas);
 mZaidejai.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not adding any values to it. And your **list is empty** and add some values to it like `list.add("hyd");
list.add("city");`
and pass those values to adapter

Answer (score 0):

Rather doing

```
adapter.add(input);
```

Do

```
list.add(input);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is wrong.

ArrayAdapter add method internally calls notifyDataSetChanged.
Please check Android source code at this [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java)

Answer (score 0):

So, as others have said you should change the `adapter.add(input);` on the `onClick` method to

```
list.add(input);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also, on an unrelated matter, you should really move the `list.remove(position);` call to the following `onClick` method of the positive button, before the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` call, so it wont be removed if the user cancels the action :)

Comment: I did that, hovewer when im trying to get the first value with list.get(0) method it still tells me: Invalid index 0, size is 0. Maybe i need to use a different method or is it still not populating the list?

Comment: some more info on where you call list.get(0) are needed then, to see whats wrong

Comment: Edited my first post. At first i tried to get the names in a string as a bundle and it worked. However i want to get the values one by one, for example the middle value so i need to access the list directly. Or is that not possible? if i simply add list.add("something") it is displayed.

Comment: ok so, you list is empty, as the ZaidimasActivity class doesnt have any data of the ZaidejaiActivity class.
To get the data you need, you need to check how to pass data between activities: http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/passing-data-between-activities.html

Comment: To pass the list as a bundle you must use putStringArrayList() and getStringArrayList()

Comment: np, you can accept the answer as correct if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

at the first time your list adapter is empty (getCount() = 0) and you do -1 in the for

```
   mBtnPradeti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // count items
            int i;

          if (adapter.getCount() > 0)
          {

            for (i = adapter.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                String obj = adapter.getItem(i);
                // send items to other activity

                Intent pradetiZaidima = new Intent(v.getContext(), ZaidimasActivity.class);
                pradetiZaidima.putExtra("playerList", obj);
                startActivity(pradetiZaidima);

            }

          }

        }
    });
```

and for this code : 
         mZaidejas.setText(list.get(0));

but on Create your list is empty !!!